# Model accuracy stuck at 0.2505. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to make an emotion classifier using face expressions with FER2013 dataset. It contains of 35887 samples with 2304 features each and an integer label 0-6 for emotions. When I was using Conv1D with shape (2304,1) then it achieved training accuracy of ~86% but wasn't doing well on any unseen test image. So I thought of reshaping it to (48,48,1) for each sample and using Conv2D on it. But now it just gets stuck on 0.2505 while training after the 2nd epoch and never increases. What's happening?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from skimage import transform
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

emotion = {0 : 'Angry', 1 : 'Disgust',2 : 'Fear',3 : 'Happy',
           4 : 'Sad',5 : 'Surprise',6 : 'Neutral'}
df=pd.read_csv('fer.csv')
faces=df.values[:,1]
faces=faces.tolist()
emos=df.values[:,0]

for i in range(len(faces)):
    faces[i]=[int(x) for x in faces[i].split()]
    emos[i]=int(emos[i])

faces=np.array(faces)
faces=transform.resize(faces, (35887,48,48))

faces=np.expand_dims(faces, axis=3)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(48, (3,3), padding='same', input_shape=(48,48,1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(48, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(96, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(96, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(192, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(192, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(384, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(384, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(384, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(192, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(96, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
    
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer='adam',
            metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(faces,emos,epochs=100,batch_size=48)
model.save_weights('model.h5')
```

### Model Accuracy Curves

[image]

### Model Loss Curves

[image]

Comment: Could you place your loss and accuracy training curves split in train and test? It would be very helpful. At first it seems that you have overfitting, a too big of a network. Are the features normalized?

Comment: @IgnacioPeletier No the features were not normalized. However, after normalizing them, the model with Conv1D (for 2304,1 shape) also gets stuck at 0.2515 now (before it was getting upto 0.86). I will post the loss and accuracy training curves of the model with Conv2D (for 48,48,1 shape) in a while.

Comment: I will wait for your curves, then we can think about your problem!

Comment: @IgnacioPeletier I have edited my post. Please have a look at the curves :)

Comment: hmmm! I was excited to see this. Taking a look at the curves we can see what can be overfitting, sin the test loss does not go now down and some bias... since you do not go up in precision. Since you are using features of images, is there any reason on using a convolutional layers? I would recommend you to use fully connected layers if the inputs are features. Either do that or use the images as inputs and keep with the Conv2d layers. Keep me updated!

Comment: Any updates? :D

Comment: @IgnacioPeletier I used `BatchNormalization()`after every layer and it fixed it.

Comment: how are the new curves?

Comment: @IgnacioPeletier I have edited the answer and added the final model and the new curves :)

Comment: It looks overfitted. Reduce the network size and/or add regularization and/or more drop out. You are getting there though!

Answer (score 3):

Normalizing the output batch after each layer fixes the issue.

#### Just add

```py
model.add(BatchNormalization())
```

after every layer.

### EDIT :

Thought that I should add more information here.
So, this was the final model I ended up making.

```py
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(200,200,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(len(classes), activation='softmax'))
            
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                    optimizer='nadam',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And these were the results I got with it.

[image]

I increased the nodes and changed the optimizer too but it was the batch normalisation which gave a dramatic increase in accuracy. Using more nodes and nadam optimizer further helped a bit.

Comment: Thank you, adding "model.add(BatchNormalization())" helped my GRU based model which was stuck at the random choice accuracy value.